# Cannot rename into certain file names on NTFS

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have a strange problem. I have an external NTFS disk, and would like to rename a file. However, when I try to rename it in Finder, I get "Error -36". In the Terminal, I get

> mv: failed to access 'Ice Cream.avi': Input/output error

The wierd thing is that I can rename it into certain names, for example `an ice cream.avi`, `ce cream.avi`, but not `the ice cream.avi` or `ice age.avi`.

It appears that I cannot use names starting with `I`, `T`, `Q`. For some reason, `gfIce202.avi` works, but not `gIce202.avi`. It looks completely arbitrary, but once a combination doesn't work it never works. What is going on here?

Comment: What are you using to enable NTFS write?

Comment: @Tetsujin good question, `UID=<...> none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`in /etc/fstab . By the way, I just renamed in on a Windows PC and it worked. But it is really odd and I'm curious what was going on.

Comment: ah, so the 'hidden' native implementation. Not used it in years, sorry. It always had random bugs, I gave up & went with Paragon.

Comment: Yeah, I expected it to have bugs, but so far never had problems (except that it requires nobrowse, which hides the drive from the finder sidebar). This is especially strange, I'm guessing what the cause could be? Faulty hashtable implementation? Anyway, I'm going to try Paragon, and will leave this here in case anybody else gets that error.